# Erroneous iOS8 status bar?

Tags: ios, swift, ios8

I'm working on an app that runs on iOS7 and iOS8 which has only one screen that supports multiple orientations, other screens should not rotate. To accomplish this, I enable all 'Device Orientation' settings app-wide in the app's plist, and have each controller return its own orientation settings.

The interface orientation behavior is now correct, with the exception of the status bar on iOS8 only. Here's some screenshots of the simplest way to reproduce the issue:

When the device is in portrait, everything is OK.
[image: When the device is in portrait, everything is OK.]

On iOS7, rotating the device doesn't cause any issues.
[image: On iOS7, rotating the device doesn't cause any issues.]

On iOS8, rotating the device causes the status bar to also rotate, but the rest of the interface does not.

[image: On iOS8, rotating the device causes the status bar to also rotate, but the rest of the interface does not.]

This demo app has only one view controller. Here's the Swift code:

```
import UIKit
class TestController: UIViewController {
    override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> Int {
        return Int(UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait.rawValue)
    }
}
```

Is there a way to fix or work around this issue in iOS8?

Comment: Nice screen shots. :) Could you post the demo app somewhere, such as github, where I can download and try it? I've seen this sort of issue in the very early days of iOS 8, but I'm a little hazy on what would cause it now. My guess is that there is something wrong elsewhere (in your Info.plist, or in the `applicationDidFinishLaunching` code), but it would be simplest if I could just see for myself.

Comment: Despite [the `UIViewController` class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/)'s claim that "in iOS 8, all rotation-related methods are deprecated", iOS 8 still calls and respects `supportedInterfaceOrientations(:_)`. (This wasn't true in early beta seeds). A new sample project I created in Xcode 6.3.1 works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the comments, they helped to point me in the right direction. My previous attempt to simplify the problem was still within the original app, and the issue could not be reproduced in a totally new app...

The issue was caused by having more than one UIWindow. The other window is used for modally presenting information in some situations, so we just have it invisibly hovering on top of everything else. However, this can be a bad approach because that window will hijack some of the calls that the original window should receive.